# Python: "gibberish sentence generator", misbehaving in a weird manner

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to create a simple "gibberish generator" program in Python that prints a string of random gibberish consisting of characters, spaces and a punctuation mark at the end (a complete sentence in other words). It's basically working already, but I've run into a weird problem that I just cant get my head around.

Somehow the last "word" in my gibberish string is always getting longer than it should be, despite my code explicitly restricting any of the words getting longer than 11 characters. After going through the code for god knows how many times I still don't get what could possibly be causing this. Funny thing is, it only becomes truly noticeable with long strings, while short sentences (up to 50 chars) look mostly fine.

These are two example outputs I'm getting when I run it in Windows powershell:

first with 50 chars:

> How many gibberish characters would you like to print out? 50
>
> Uxlouasieyt uoygigjas eayouiumza gyfejmu th egkyaulheeb.

second with 300 chars:

> How many gibberish characters would you like to print out? 300
>
> Yhiaztexj ekkexe iiuiyx itozlyui zao cegyeuyiml aofzyyreet cofi owzycwobla rreyblioca rla tpocnelavj ytpa
> x eefra gnyoe yfxyhnivme miert ywy ykhi ee gup eui ttuoi oeoyaf uenyecb apluo yli xmy uiyaoneewe jyxymxal
> y dzaiglu uo eqkiyeiz ke oxayuiayzf yyi iqoezu ekuioyotly viyslaybiiwvymitoeagrejvavihigpyoxawefunodgu!

Notice how the last word in the sentence is getting progressively longer with longer strings, while all the precluding words stay within 11 characters. It's as if the part of the code where the spaces are added in the gibberish_list is being ignored after some point. But why?

Here is the code in full:

```
import random

def gibberishgen():
    alphabet_vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','y',]
    alphabet_consonants = ['b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','v','w','x','z']
    gibberish_list = []
    
    while True:
        gibberishamount = raw_input("How many gibberish characters would you like to print out? ")
        if gibberishamount.isdigit():
            break
        else:
            print "Please give me a number!"
    
    # fill the gibberish_list with characters
    lasttwochars = ['','']
    for char in range(1, int(gibberishamount)+1):
        nextcharvowel = random.choice(alphabet_vowels)
        nextcharconsonant = random.choice(alphabet_consonants)
        if lasttwochars[0] in alphabet_consonants and lasttwochars[1] in alphabet_consonants:   # because I don't want more than 2 consonants in a row
            nextchar = nextcharvowel
        else:
            roll = random.randint(1,10)
            if roll > 5:
                nextchar = nextcharvowel
            else:   
                nextchar = nextcharconsonant
        gibberish_list.append(nextchar)
        lasttwochars.append(nextchar)
        lasttwochars.pop(0)
    
    # insert spaces at randomized intervals to separate the "words" from each other
    last_whitespace = 0
    for index in range(0, len(gibberish_list)+1):
        randspace = random.randint(1,10)
        if index >= last_whitespace + 3 and randspace <= 2:     # make sure words don't get too short on average
            gibberish_list.insert(index, ' ')
            last_whitespace = index
        elif index > last_whitespace + 10:                      # ...or too long
            gibberish_list.insert(index, ' ')
            last_whitespace = index
    
    punctlist = ['.', '!', '?']
    
    gibberishstring = ''.join(gibberish_list)
    finalstring = gibberishstring.capitalize() + random.choice(punctlist)
    print "\n", finalstring, "\n"
    
gibberishgen()
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone explained to me what is going on in here. I'm only two months into learning python so yeah, It's very much possible I missed something that should be obvious.

Also feel free to point out any bad syntax or practice you spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're inserting spaces in `gibberish_list`, it gets longer and longer, but your loop stops at the character index that corresponds to the last character in `gibberish_list` when you *started* the iteration, so it never reaches the end of the list, which becomes more apparent the more spaces you're inserting (i.e. for longer strings).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Actually I cant believe I didn't think of that,  so obvious now that you pointed it out. Thanks for clearing things up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat extended version:

It works in both Python 2.x and 3.x and uses realistic letter- and word-length frequencies.

```
from itertools import islice
from random import choice, randint
import sys

if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    inp = raw_input
    rng = xrange
else:
    inp = input
    rng = range


LETTERS = (    # relative character frequencies
    "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabb"
    "bbbbbbbbbbcccccccccccccccccccccdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddde"
    "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee"
    "eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeefffffffffffffffffgggggggggggggggg"
    "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
    "iiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiijjkkkkkklllllllllllllllllllll"
    "llllllllllmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"
    "nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo"
    "ooooooooopppppppppppppppqrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"
    "rrrrrrsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssstttttttttt"
    "ttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttuuuuuu"
    "uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuvvvvvvvvwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwxxxyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyzz"
)

CONSONANTS  = ''.join(ch for ch in LETTERS if ch not in "aeiouy")
VOWELS      = ''.join(ch for ch in LETTERS if ch     in "aeiouy")
PUNCTUATION = "....??!"

is_cons     = set(CONSONANTS).__contains__    # is_cons(x) == x in set(CONSONANTS)

WORDLEN = [     # relative word-length frequencies
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  2,
    2,  2,  2,  2,  2,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
    3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3,
    3,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
    4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,  4,
    5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,  5,
    5,  5,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,  6,
    7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  7,  8,  8,  8,  8,
    8,  9,  9,  9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12
]

wordlen = lambda: choice(WORDLEN)

def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(inp(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            pass

def gibberish():
    """
    Generate an infinite sequence of random letters,
      allowing no more than two consecutive consonants
    """
    a = choice(LETTERS); yield a
    b = choice(LETTERS); yield b
    while True:
        c = choice(VOWELS if is_cons(a) and is_cons(b) else LETTERS)
        yield c
        a, b = b, c

def take_n(iterable, n):
    return list(islice(iterable, n))

def add_spaces(iterable, make_word_length):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    while True:
        for i in rng(make_word_length()):
            yield next(iterable)
        yield ' '

def gibberish_sentence():
    length   = get_int("How many characters of gibberish would you like? ")
    chars    = take_n(gibberish(), length)              # make that many chars
    chars    = add_spaces(chars, wordlen)               # add spaces to make "words"
    sentence = ''.join(chars).rsplit(' ', 1)[0]         # crop at last space (don't leave a part-word at the end)
    return sentence.capitalize() + choice(PUNCTUATION)  # capitalize and add punctuation

def main():
    print(gibberish_sentence())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Sample output:

```
How many characters of gibberish would you like? 180
Ahisent anoe tfon evaer an irpenn otjievt ecfiotuee ebaa wtah sav hii lti
ukt erd elrihe dewa st aosdeec zenle acju ld eeaotl entetom wisvos
aeatresl oixb atidb eekermo nteu darso hligseoanei vhaeoedse qyr sogudc.
```